# Spring message shows only first word

Tags: spring-mvc, properties-file

I have a message property file. I have a property like;

```
header.signInBtn = Sign In
```

When I try to show this on an button using

```
<input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="SignIn"
                    value=<spring:message code="header.signInBtn"/> />
```

it shows only "sign" but not sign in.

I am using Spring and I don't know what is the problem. Also I couldn't find any resource about this problem.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried putting your string in quotes? header.signInBtn="Sign In"?

Comment: thank you. I didn't know this makes difference

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, just a suggestion. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I'm not sure if quoting the message in properties file is the best solution here. Better solution would probably be to put quotes around the `<spring:message>` tag like this: `value="<spring:message code="header.signInBtn" />"`.

Comment: thanks. I guess this is better :)